# Deploying only some of the dependencies with maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I have a problem that I do not know how solve it properly. I'm developing plugins for a program that loads these plugins dynamically on start up. Everything worked out very well so far as I usually only do use dependencies like Apache Commons which have been used by the main program, too.

Now I tried to play around with Google Guice and the main program does not have the package in the class path and so there is a NoClassDefFoundError at start up of course. I used google for a while to find a solution to my problem but the only thing I came up with was using an uber jar. The problem with that is, that I do have dependencies to other plugins that I use and I don't want to pull them in my plugin as I would end up having to manage all of them. It might even happen that I have two different implementations in the class path because I lost track and did not update that minor version. Unfortunately there is usually no interface for other plugins so I cannot take that in.

Long text, short question: is it possible to tell Maven to only pull Guice in the file or, even better, is there a cleaner solution to this problem? Maybe I even did miss something crucial in the whole process? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so there is a particular dependency which you want just on runtime in package ? (not in compile, test) right ?

Comment: I need it at compile time, too, so it's all three, compile, test and runtime.

Comment: You can create custom assembly with assembly plugin

Comment: Is there a way to tell the assembly plugin to package only chosen dependencies? I have to look this up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found a solution that works. Using the shade plugin like this yields the needed results:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                    <includes>
                        <include>com.google.inject:guice</include>
                    </includes>
                </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the classpath of main program doesn't jave Guice jar, the parent classloader doesn't load Guice package. If a child classloader is loading the Guice jar then main program won't have any knowledge of it. Now to tackle this problem you can do either of below :

- Move Guice jar to the classpath of your main program
- Moe the portion of code which is using Guice jar to child classloader (plugin)

Comment: The main program is not using Guice, that's my problem. The main program does not have this dependency and so I cannot use it without a fat jar which I want to avoid.

Comment: then where do you get NoClassDefFoundError?

Comment: It's when I load the plugin. I put it in the plugin folder, start the program and as soon as the main program loads my plugin it tries to use the classloader to load the Module class from guice which does not exists in the class path.

Comment: and did you see a ClassNotFoundException or ExceptionIntializerError below? Check this out for why I asked this - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Module - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.Module - so the class is not there and that's just my problem, it is not in the jar file which is created and I want it to be there and just this one dependency, not all of those I use in the plugin.

Comment: So that makes it tricky.. You want to use Module class, but can't include Guice jar in your jar. A possible alternative would be put Guice jar in your server or system classpath, but that is usually not recommended